# Hi-hat cymbals' differences

Tags: cymbals

Just had another pair of hi-hat cymbals, and notice that there's one marked 'top' or 'T', the other 'bottom' or 'B'. Is there a difference between the two? What would that be? Is it crucial that they are placed accordingly?

Surely it's not a ploy to sell more cymbals?!

Comment: You need two cymbals for hi-hat anyway, so how would labeling them as top and bottom sell more than just a pair?

Comment: @ojs - they could be sold separately, priced differently, don't know, hence the ?!

Comment: So, are they actually sold separately or do you just think they could be?! Add explanation marks! as needed?!

Comment: @ojs - I don't know. Never had to buy a single hi-hat cymbal, all mine came in pairs, and none damaged, before or by me. But, judging by the answers/comments, each could be purchased separately, as each is apparently different.

Comment: Don't call me Shirley

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - how did you know the question was for you..? Is that your middle name - a hated secret?

Comment: @Mazura - ZBTs. And it seems there's a slight upturn on the top one, although as they come together, surely it wouldn't matter which way up they were.

Comment: @Tim Regarding Carl Witthoft's "Shirley" comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KM2K7sV-K74

Answer (score 16):

There can be differences, yes. The bottom one is heavier/thicker and the top lighter/thinner. This is why some drummers flip their hats and play to have the heavier one on top.

One advantage is having the characteristics of more than one cymbal profile in your hat sound, so you can have the agility of a thin top and the complexity of a thicker bottom.

See https://drummingbase.com/top-vs-bottom-hi-hat-differences-and-setup/

Comment: Thanks. Just found some scales! My Pearls are 23% difference, and Zildjians 20% difference. I guess rockers will prefer heavier tops, while jazzers like lighter tops better. I also guess one could make up one's own set, with whatever cymbals one liked, same/different, as long as they're both 14" (or 13").

Comment: I have a pair of [Zildjian Quick Beat HHs](https://zildjian.com/products/a-zildjian-quick-beat-hihats) and the top and bottom are extremely different: The bottom has holes and lacks a bell.

Comment: @Theodore - that would surely make the bottom a *lot* lighter than the top..?

Comment: @Tim I'd say it's not split rock/jazz but more by drummer style. Some metal drummers like a lighter top for more agility and crispness, some metal drummers like a heavier top for brasher sounds and to withstand harder playing.

Comment: @tim well Theodore’s hats could well be much thicker on the bottom and the holes are there to aid resonance. There’s not enough info given, but the lower hat is generally heavier.

Comment: @Tim I have them stored at the moment, so I can't weigh them, but IIRC, the bottom is thicker, which may make it heavier despite the holes and difference in profile.  The holes are there to relieve air and make them close faster.

Answer (score 5):

Just had another pair of [New Beat](https://zildjian.com/products/a-zildjian-new-beat-hihats) hi-hat cymbals where the top cracked, *again*. Can I just use two bottoms or will it sound like crap? Yes and yes. It will also turn your sticks into sawdust slightly faster.

"sensitive enough for light jazz, but, on the other end of the spectrum, loud and powerful enough for hard rock and heavy metal"

> Inspired by Louie Bellson, Zildjian introduces 'New Beat' HiHats, matched with a lighter top cymbal but heavier bottom for a more pronounced "chick" sound. 'New Beats' become standard equipment for all drummers overnight. [c. 1963]

> Basically hi hats tended to be about the same weight on the top and bottom. Say within 80g, and often within 50g. Hi hats in this "equal weight" or "matched" tradition continue to be offered, but most manufacturers also have a New Beat style pair in their hi hat offerings. And what is this magic New Beat ratio?

> The usual formula is given as 2:3 for top:bottom. That ratio can also be expressed as 67% and the average across all the pairs I've collected up (52 pairs and counting) is 71%. But the variation in individual pairings goes from 60% to 80% (in rounded figures).

> *A Brief History of New Beats* https://black.net.nz/avedis/new-beats.html

Comment: I don't understand how the "sensitive enough for light jazz..." sentence fits into the rest of this answer, but otherwise, there is some good information here.